# Confusion with form validation using Kotlin and rx-java combineLatest

Tags: kotlin, rx-java, rx-java2, rx-android, rx-binding

So I wanted to use rx-java2 for form validation. I'm using Kotlin. I encountered two problems. Both emailObservable and passwordObservable are of type `Disposable!`. I tried to specify type by calling `val emailObservable: Observable<Boolean>` but Android Studio thinks its `Disposable!`.

Secondly when I wanted to use method `combineLatest` I got an error: None of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied.

Both emailObservable and passwordObservable work correctly.
I'm new to rx-java and I'm confused about this type thing.

```
val emailObservable = RxTextView.afterTextChangeEvents(textEmail)
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .map { x -> textEmail.text.length > 3 }
                .subscribe { x -> foo(x) }

val passwordObservable =RxTextView.afterTextChangeEvents(textPassword)
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .map { x -> textPassword.text.length > 5 }
                .subscribe { x -> foo(x) }


Observable.combineLatest(emailObservable,
passwordObservable,
BiFunction { x: Boolean, y:Boolean -> x && y })
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Concerning the `Disposable` vs `Observable` actually the compiler/IDE is correct. The `subscribe` method is called on an `Observable` and returns a `Disposable`, i.e., something you can use to unsubscribe from the `Observable` before it completes (sort of "cancel").

Then the `combineLatest` method expects to be called with 2 `Observable`s, while you are supplying 2 `Disposable`s.
To solve the issue, you should not call `subscribe` directly in the chain, but on the result of `combineLatest`.

Example:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val first = Observable.intervalRange(1, 10, 0, 2, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    val second = Observable.intervalRange(10, 20, 0, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)

    Observable.combineLatest(arrayOf(first, second)) {
        "${it[0]} -> ${it[1]}"
    }.blockingSubscribe() {
        println(it)
    }
}
```

Output:

```
1 -> 10
1 -> 11
2 -> 11
2 -> 12
2 -> 13
...
```